# Help me on my app version 2

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store

I have one iPhone app in app store, in that application my in app purchase was working correctly.

again submited my another version of application without changing the code but now the in app purchase it is not working...

Please help me out, why my in app purchase is not working actually.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information here for anyone to be able to truly help you resolve this issue. All anyone can do is speculate as to what might be the cause.

Comment: I kept receiving iTunes Connect emails saying that they are shutting down services during Christmas time. Could this be a possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

Check Whether it is showing "Clear for sale" status for in app purchase items in itunes.